# Google speech-to-text api request getting denied because "the billing account for the owning project is disabled in state closed"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-speech-to-text-api

This is very weird.

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
return Object.assign(new Error(message), status);
                     ^

Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state closed
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (C:\Dev\Personal\test-speech-to-text\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call.js:31:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Dev\Personal\test-speech-to-text\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client.js:180:52)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Dev\Personal\test-speech-to-text\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:365:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Dev\Personal\test-speech-to-text\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:328:181)
    at C:\Dev\Personal\test-speech-to-text\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:182:78
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
  code: 7,
  details: 'The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state closed',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} },
  note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'
}
```

I have tried contacting support and they have insisted that my billing account is set correctly and enabled.

I'd appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have more than one project and/or more than one billing account. Go to the billing account and make sure the project is listed. Your question has no details on your project/organization or how it is set up for billing. The error message says that the billing account is closed which is not the same as disabled due to a payment issue.

Comment: My project is indeed listed, and it’s billing account is active. However neither the project nor the billing account belong to any organization.

Comment: Since we cannot help you with billing problems, you must contact Google Cloud Billing support again and clarify the problem and the solution.